# Nested set model build tree from node to JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, tree, nested

I am working to build a category hierarchical like this:

Home

```
- Car
  - Yellow
  - Red
- Animal
  - Cat
     - Node1
     - Node2
  - Dog
```

I use php & mysql schema with nested set model:

```
- left
- right
- id
```

I want to get a tree from a Animal node to result and JSON structure this:

```
- Animal
  - Cat
     - Node1
     - Node2
  - Dog
```

I dont have any solution for that. Please help me !

Comment: If you're using nested set, then you need to do select with condition ` where left >= Animal's left and right <= Animal's right`.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old , but maybe it helps other. Good article written in german including sql queries. 
http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/